# Algorithm to find region with least-probable density

Tags: algorithms, complexity

Consider the following boolean array where dark == true:

[image: graphic representation of boolean array]

In this scenario the probability that a cell is dark or light is 50/50, but this may not be true for the general case.

Maximizing only on density we see that cells 12 to 16 (inclusive) have the largest area with 100% dark coverage.  Using [this binomial probability calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx) we find that the p-value for finding 5 contiguous dark cells (P(X>=5)) is 0.03125.

However, in cells 12 to 21 the density is not 100%, but the overall p-value is lower (e.g. less probability that this region's density randomly occurred).  There are 9 dark cells out of 10 total cells, which yields a p-value of 0.0107421875.

I would like an algorithm that effeciently finds the region of least probable density.

Keep in mind that this array may be large and that there may be improbably dense light regions near improbably dense dark regions so that the combined regions have balanced light/dark ratios.  Like so:

[image]

The number of possible regions within an array of size N is 1 + 2 + .. + N = (N + 1)N/2 which gives us an upper bound complexity of O(N^2).  Are there any algorithms with lower complexity?

**EDIT 1**: Restated in terms of coin-flipping:  There are two coins.  One is fair, and one is weighted to come up heads most of the time.  Someone flips the fair coin for several flips, flips the weighted coin for several flips, then goes back to flipping the fair coin.  All we have are the record of flips.  How can we best guess the region in that list where the weighted coin was used?

This may be an open problem as this was [recently covered](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i84i1X9k8_g&feature=youtu.be&list=PLZdCLR02grLofiMKo0bCeLHZC0_2rpqsz&t=578) as an area for machine learning.  ML aside, I'm curious what the lowest-complexity deterministic algorithm is.

Comment: The least density is where the longest consecutive false-area is located. Just track that with a counter.

Comment: ... which should be `O(n)`.

Comment: @ThomasKilian this is least-probable density, not simply lest density.

Comment: Well, the probability for a true in a completely false area is 0. So this is least-probable. Except you have to offer a negative probability.

Comment: A running average could also be used if you are looking for more than simply consecutive consistent areas.